# PHP Array - Odd data when saving to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a PHP array that I am saving to a MySQL Database:

```
 $q35list = serialize($_POST["q35list"]);
```

Using `mysqli_prepare` I am saving successfully to the database.

What is odd is that I have a mix of data being stored:

`s:0:"";` - fine as user has not selected anything.

`s:55:"Set[]=6&Set[]=4&Set[]=3&Set[]=7&Set[]=2&Set[]=5&Set[]=1";` - fine as user has selected options and this appears correctly saved.

But, I am getting a few odd ones, that I can neither replicate or understand how/what/why this is being saved:

`s:4:"s:4:";`
`s:5:"s:55:";`
`s:4:"s:8:";`

Has anyone come across this/ know what this might be and would be kind enough to provide an explanation?

Comment: Looks like data that has been serialized twice. "s:55:", as a string, is five characters long, and so becomes `s:5:"s:55:";`. Verify your serializing workflow.

Comment: Iserni - any ideas why/ how it got serialized twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its hard to say what happend here but it looks like a double serialisation with errors.

The most common way to avoid problems with serialisation is to base64 encode after serialisation before save to db:

```
//serialize
$string = base64_encode(serialize($array));

//unserialize
$array = unserialize(base64_decode($string));
```

Comment: steven - thanks for this - I guess what I find odd is that I'm only serializing the numbers `1234567` as you can see, not text or long text etc.  Really appreciate the heads up on using base64 to encode/ decode.  Will try it!